# Flutter Gesture Detector onTap not working but on double tap working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a todo list application and I have wrapped a textform field in a gesture detector in a list tile however the `onTap` gesture does not fire but the `onDoubleTap` gesture does:

todolist_screen.dart:

```
class TodoListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function() onSettingsPress;
  final void Function() onInit;
  final void Function(int id) deleteTodo;
  final void Function(Todo todo) toggleComplete;
  final List<Todo> todos;

  TodoListScreen(
      {required this.onSettingsPress,
      required this.onInit,
      required this.deleteTodo,
      required this.toggleComplete,
      this.todos = const []});

  @override
  _TodoScreenState createState() => _TodoScreenState();
}

class _TodoScreenState extends State<TodoListScreen> {
  dynamic myList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.onInit();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25))),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              builder: (context) => FractionallySizedBox(
                    heightFactor: 0.8,
                    child: AddTodoModalContainer(),
                  ));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todos'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), onPressed: widget.onSettingsPress)
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: widget.todos
                    .map((todo) => TodoItem(
                        id: todo.id,
                        title: todo.title,
                        completed: todo.completed,
                        deleteTodo: widget.deleteTodo,
                        toggleComplete: (value) {
                          widget.toggleComplete(todo);
                        }))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

todo_item.dart:

```
class TodoItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.completed,
      required this.toggleComplete,
      required this.deleteTodo})
      : super(key: key);

  final int id;
  final String title;
  final bool completed;
  final void Function(bool?) toggleComplete;
  final void Function(int id) deleteTodo;

  @override
  _TodoItemState createState() => _TodoItemState();
}

class _TodoItemState extends State<TodoItem> {
  late final TextEditingController _controller;
  late final FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
  }

  bool isActive = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Checkbox(
        value: widget.completed,
        onChanged: widget.toggleComplete,
      ),
      trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever_sharp),
          onPressed: () {
            widget.deleteTodo(widget.id);
          }),
      title: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('tapped');
          setState(() {
            isActive = !isActive;
          });
        },
        child: TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          initialValue: widget.title,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.title,
              border: isActive
                  ? UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 5,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          color: Colors.black))
                  : InputBorder.none),
          readOnly: !isActive,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

P.S I tried adding the behaviour property to the Gesture Detector but they all did not work

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking a few widgets I realised the problem. TextFormField already has an onTap property hence it took precedence over the Gesture Detector's onTap property.